# Install OpenSSL using Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, openssl, devops

I want to install OpenSSL using an Ansible on an Ansible Playbook on Linux.

Would it be somthing like this -

```
- name: OPENSSL | Installation
  package:
    name:
      - openssl
    state: present
```

And would I need pip(Python) as well for this to work ?

Answer (score 2):

No, [package module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html) only install system package.

This modules uses the underlying OS package manager (apt, yum, ...)

Comment: Thanks, so I am going to run my playbook on linux, how would I use yum to install openssl ?

Comment: @trying2dev Just use 'package' module to install openssl, this module will install your package with the package manager installled on your system

Comment: So what I have in my original question is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Most distros already come with OpenSSL installed by default. You just need pip or pip3 if you're gonna use the pip/pip3 Ansible modules, otherwise you're just gonna need Python3 (see a list of Ansible's [prerequisites](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#prerequisites)). Some modules may require aditional Python modules or libraries. You can check if you have OpenSSL by just typing `openssl version` on a terminal.

Comment: Thanks, so I am using my playbook to create a VM using terraform and then installing some software on it, one is Openssl, so whats the best way to do that?

Comment: It depends what you plan to do with that VM and what's your cloud provider. If you're planing to use a development environment with VirtualBox, perhaps Vagrant + Ansible is a good way, if you're building a cloud image, I'll suggest Packer + Ansible + Terraform to deploy it. =)